Use a pair of half-bridge drivers to make a full-bridge driver
I intend to use a pair of half-bridge drivers and a logic gate to make a full-bridge driver for controlling my DC motors with 3 standard input pins of Enable, Direction, and Arduino PWM.
I looked at a variety of half-bridge gate driver datasheets and noticed that there are mostly two types of driver
one with a high-side, low-side signal and the other with Enable, PWM signal.
For example, the following block diagram is  L6388ED driver

and this one is  LN8322 driver

My question is:
What would be a connection diagram if I want to bind two half-bridges of the same type and have Enable, Direction PWM input pin these two types of gate drive?
I might add, that I've selected all gate drives which have a 5 V logic level input.

these two types of gate drive ... it is unclear what that means  ... are you using two half bridges of different type?

sorry, I mean two half bridges of the same  type to make an h-bridge with 3 pins(En, PWM,Dir)

why do you have two different driver modules? ... please update your post and clarify it

What are these diagrams from? Please provide citations for materials used in the post, thanks.

I think the first one is  L6388ED  and the second one is LN8322, but those are examples of two types. And my question is if I pick either of these types, how should be wired together with the logic gate to get 3 pins of En, Dir, and PWM

You only need 2 pins from a microcontroller. You can adjust forward, reverse, and stop by modulating the PWM of each half-bridge appropriately.

Arduino pwm is usually around 500Hz which is probably not sufficient for either of those ics.

@Kartman datasheet never said anything for minimum frequency

Yes, but the assumption is that you understand how the device works. In the L6388E datasheet see section 7 bootstrap driver.
